# Open Graph Aggregation not previewing or posting

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-apps, aggregation

We have created a application that has a few open graph actions available for it.

One of our actions have been approved,the action posts perfectly and aggregating on the user timeline is great as well.

Our 2nd action has been approved and the action posts perfectly, but the aggregation is no where to be found.

The confusion comes in because we have a staging/sandbox app that we use to test out features before releasing them, and the EXACT same settings in the OpenGraph app setting panel, produce the desired results on the staging/sandbox app but do not work for the production version.

Seeing as the aggregation settings page was identical we checked the sample data popup.
The sandbox app correctly previews the aggregation,
while the production app show the default image that displays before you put any sample actions/objects in.

The aggregation is using a filter but I have double checked that the filter is correct. I have also removed the filter to see if I had somehow made a mistake.

Also, this is not a problem with the publishing of the action, as the action is still appearing on the newsfeed, timeline and other areas where we'd assume to see it.

Has anyone had this problem before?